# Preventing admin users from accessing other admin users’ files

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2008, file-permissions, administrator

Is there a way to prevent a user who has administrator privileges from accessing the files of another user with admin privileges in Windows Server 2008?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent admin users from reading my files](http://superuser.com/questions/914467/prevent-admin-users-from-reading-my-files), [How can I limit other (administrator) users access to my profile?](http://superuser.com/questions/132132/how-can-i-limit-other-administrator-users-access-to-my-profile)

Answer (score -1):

You could remove all domain admin user group permissions and just allow that individual user permission to the home folder.