# Windows, prevent file access even to admin

Tags: windows-7, permissions, user-accounts

I mostly work on Mac but have a Windows problem: 
I need to prevent access to specific files to all (even administrator).
I'm running a local nodeJs server app, and need to prevent access to the main script.
In short I need to prevent tempering with the program.

I know IIS has 'special' users for example, preventing access from any 'standard user', but not sure that prevents access from an admin.

Is there any way to prevent access to a file even to an administrator? 
Special User permissions? 
My guess is that an admin would always be able to change user permissions, so I'm not sure it's possible but there may be 'special' accounts that can be used?

Any hints / direction as to where to look would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: you can always take away permissions from an admin account or the Administrators group, but that doesn't provide a meaningful security barrier, as an admin can by definition take ownership of any file object, and from there set their own permissions, even overriding existing deny permissions. Ownership can be taken but not given back, so that if someone takes ownership of an object innapropriately, they can be held responsible later.  Thats about all you can do. you can't lock `root` out of files on *nix either, since they can chown/chmod to their hearts content.

Comment: I thought in Windows the 'System' had some specific privileges that maybe could be used to do this. Isn't there files/folders that even an admin can't access?

Comment: Also see: [How can I limit other (administrator) users access to my profile?](http://superuser.com/questions/132132/how-can-i-limit-other-administrator-users-access-to-my-profile)

Comment: @MrE, Not on the file system level.